# Can't find method org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession() in hibernate 5.3.5.Final and spring boot 1.5.4 integration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Using hibernate 5.3.5.Final and spring boot 1.5.4 & JPA jars. Hibernate 3.6 jar is working fine but i don't want to downgrade my hibernate jar. So what is the solution to use  hibernate 5.3.5.Final in spring boot with JPA integration?

Comment: Where did you get `Hibernate` Version `5.3.5.Final` from? The most current that is available should be version `5.2.15.Final`. Also why do you want to open a session on your own, when using `Spring Data JPA`? You could just use repositories for database access

Comment: Using hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar and I want to integrate hibernate 3.6 jar to spring boot with JPA. Whenever I'm calling  any of the class file in hibernate 3.6 jar , I'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session; Please assist to resolve

Comment: Hibernate validator 5.3 doesn't support hibernate 3.6. You need to use a newer version of hibernate. Hiberate-validator != hibernate.

Comment: Which version of hibernate needs to be used to resolve this one? Please suggest

Comment: Also I tried with  <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version> but no luck